# How to properly lower PH while cycling a tank?

Tags: aquarium, betta

So I am a one time betta owner and while I fell like I did alright with my last Betta (his name was Columbus and he lived a happy three years with me) I really want my next fish to have a wonderful life. I have been doing lots of research on how to properly cycle my new tank, but I have run into a little problem. I just moved and it seems that the PH in the tap water at my new house is insanely high and I am STRUGGLING to get it down to a 7.0. I have been cycling the tank for about three weeks now and nothing I've tried has seemed to work. I have tried Indian Almond Leaves, no carbon filter, API PH Down and nothing seems to work. From what I can see with my test kit my PH remains at an 8.8 or possibly higher (8.8 is as high as my test kit reads) any suggestions?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your alkaline pH implies tap water is very hard. Likely it is most practical to use mostly distilled , deionized water or rain water with very little tap water ( some minerals are needed). Adding anything such as an acid like vinegar is only a short term remedy.